# "name 'boto3' is not defined"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to create basic Lambda function to connect to S3 and then do the rest of the stuff but I am stuck at the beginning to connect to S3 and getting below error while running the code .

```
import json
import boto3
import io
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        s3_Bucket_Name = "mybucket"
        s3_File_Name = "toconvert/abcd.xlsx" 
                
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Error:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "name 'boto3' is not defined",
  "errorType": "NameError",
  "requestId": "<RequestId>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 5, in lambda_handler\n    s3 = boto3.client('s3')\n"
  ]
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: <RequestId> Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] NameError: name 'boto3' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 5, in lambda_handler
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')END RequestId: <RequestId>
REPORT RequestId: <RequestId>   Duration: 13.35 ms  Billed Duration: 14 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 33 MB  Init Duration: 126.05 ms
```

Comment: Your code should run just fine. However, I notice that your code is referring to `pandas`, which suggests you are using a Lambda Layer. You might want to remove this layer and then test your code just to verify that the environment seems to be working. If it does, then the problem seems to lie with the Lambda layer that was added.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think your code piece and traceback fit together. Note that it says  `line 5, in lambda_handler\n    s3 = boto3.client('s3')` but your code shows the initialization of the client before the function definition during init in 'lambda_function.py'.

In fact, since you import boto3 it must exist in the namespace and lambda layer. Otherwise you would have already recveived an `ImportError: No module named boto3`.

Comment: Sorry if I confused you with the layer. What I meant is that I believe your lambda code posted should not throw this error. For this reason I believe that this is not the actual lambda code. Perhaps you accidentally copied an old version? Check out the official documentation about lambda Layers https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/chapter-layers.html.

Comment: Thanks for reverting back. I tried few things and somehow deleting and adding Lambda again fixed the issue. I did copied the whole code again from the reference link.